# Unit testing Controller method - assign value to base class property to avoid using Initialize()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, moq

This test is to check that I can return a ViewModel object by creating a customer and calling the Details() controller method.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Can_View_AccountDetails()
{
       AccountController target = new AccountController(null, null, null, null);
       target.customer = new Customer { Id = 4, Active = true, BillingAddress_Id=1, ShippingAddress_Id=2 };

       //  Act
       ActionResult result = target.Details();
       //  Assert
       var resultData = ((ViewResult)result).ViewData.Model as AccountViewModel;
       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(resultData, (typeof(AccountViewModel)));
}
```

'customer' is a member of the controller base class, which is then assigned in Initialize(). Initially I couldn't assign anything to it, but by setting it to 'public' rather than 'protected' I was able to use it in my test and avoided trying to call the base class Initialize() method.

EDIT: 'customer' is populate from a Repository object injected into the base class constructor.

Is this the right way to do this?  It seems somehow wrong to change the accessibility level in order to get the test to work.

Also, although I'm trying to use Moq to create my tests, I'm not actually doing any mocking at all here which again, doesn't seem right.

Comment: how does the AccountController or base controller acquire the Customer instance / customer information ?

Comment: after your update: how can you inject the customer / repository into the base class but not into the AccountController? Can you show that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your real problem is that the customer information "magically" shows up within the `AccountController`. The `Customer` instance should be injected into the `AccountController` from the outside since it is an external dependency. That being the case you would not have to make the `customer` property public because you pass it into the `AccountController` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Protected means it can only access from derived classes, so the test class would need to inherit the protected class.

Also you stubbed this as being Moq, but i don't see any Mock testing. You should be using interfaces that represent the Customer class so you can Mock the ICustomer interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stub your Repository object and set it up so that it returns customer. Then, you don't need to expose `.customer` property as `public` (or `internal`) - you simply tell repository stub to return the one you'd like:

```
var repositoryStub = new Mock<IRepository>();
var customer = new Customer { /* ... */ };
repositoryStub.Setup(r => r.GetCustomer()).Returns(customer);
```

And naturally, you need to initialize your `AccountContoller` with stubbed dependency to repository (and other ones aswell, if needed):

```
var accountController = new AccountController(repositoryStub, ...);
```

This of course assumes your `AccountController` can take repository dependency.

So now, when you call `Initialize()` on base class, it should use stubbed repository and set your private `.customer` field to the one you specified it to return during stub setup.